# C# MVC default model binder won't bind to DateTime but will to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I'm clearly missing something obvious here. As the title says, if I have this signature:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, DateTime? dateFrom, DateTime? dateTo)
```

I always get `null`'s for the `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. If I use this signature:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, string dateFrom, string dateTo)
```

I get the dates as a string as such: "27/11/2018 00:00:00" and "27/12/2018 23:59:59"

I've also tried non-nullable `DateTime` but it doesn't work either.

On the front end I have this (which is populated correctly from the model by the way):

```
<div>
    <p>Filter</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateFrom, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTo, new { @class = "form-control" })

    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.Id" asp-route-dateFrom="@Model.DateFrom" asp-route-dateTo="@Model.DateTo">Filter</a>
</div>
```

Why is the default model binder not binding to `DateTime` or `DateTime?`?

Additionally, if I inspect the `Query` in the immediate window I have:

```
Request.Query["dateFrom"]
{27/11/2018 00:00:00}
    Count: 1
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
Request.Query["dateTo"]
{27/12/2018 23:59:59}
    Count: 1
    Results View: Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
```

Edit after being marked as a duplicate:
I'm not sure the "duplicate" really explains what the problem is - Can the default model binder not bind dates? - If I `DateTime.TryParse` on my strings then I get what I need. Creating my own custom model binder seems overkill - I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here. So whilst the questions are similar, the answers to the linked to "duplicate" don't answer all my questions.

Comment: What is the defination for `model.DateFrom` and `model.DateTo`, fail to reproduce your issue with this model `    public class Bills
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Number { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

    }
`

Comment: `public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }` just basic. I managed to get it working it I submit via a form rather than querystring but it was/is very odd.

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I fail to reproduce your issue with current information.